# NodeJS: Delete futures running a thread to make new ones

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, thread-safety, future

I am working with legacy code written in Nodejs. There is a scheduler class which takes functions as input and starts a thread wrapped in a future.

`const t = threads.spawn(fn);`

```
future_ary.push(futures.newFuture(t));
```

Where the `futures` is just a wrapper class that does some book keeping and creates the futures using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/future) node library. On a subsequent call to the scheduler with new functions it needs to delete the old futures running those threads and make new ones. However, I am unable to delete the old ones. So my scheduler just spawns new ones and the old futures and threads just linger on until I stop the parent process. So how do I delete these old futures to make room for new ones?

Comment: An idea that can help you. Try to kill the related pid.